# Ошибка при запросе cURL: "Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT"

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Есть следующая проблема: при выполнении запроса к google при помощи CURL c использованием proxy  curl_exec() возвращает false и следующую ошибку "Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT".  Прошу подсказать в чем проблема.

```
$url ="https://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode($keyWorld).;
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36';
$proxy='51.79.65.157:3128';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
if ($content === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ответу прокси-сервера, CONNECT-запросы через него - запрещены. А запросы, с использованием https-протокола, именно такие.

```
[jigius@jigius tmp]$ telnet 51.79.65.157 3128
Trying 51.79.65.157...
Connected to 51.79.65.157.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: squid/3.5.12
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 17:24:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3410
X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from ADM-MANAGER
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from ADM-MANAGER:3128
Connection: close

...
<p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p>
...
```